# Parse MathML in XML and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, xml, mathml

I need to parse the MathML in XML using php

Here the sample code for MathML in my XML ([ref](http://www.abcbets.com/dependencies/mathml.txt)):

```
<mathDisplay numbered="yes" id="van005-mdis-0001">
  <mrow>
    <mrow selected="true">
      <msup><mo>sin</mo><mn>2</mn></msup>
      <mi>&theta;</mi>
      <mo>+</mo>
      <msup><mo>cos</mo><mn>2</mn></msup>
      <mi>&theta;</mi>
      <mo>=</mo><mn>1</mn>
    </mrow>
  </mrow1>
</mathDisplay>
```

Please help me to parse the mathml from XML in php

Comment: What do you mean by "parse"? You want to calculate the expression therein and highly errors if there are some?

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. Yes in XML there is a mathml expression. In attached link you can find the mathml expression. that expression is in XML. I need to get the value in between <mathDisplay> tag .

Comment: The XML is invalid, so an answer would not be helpful in this concrete case. Generally you can parse *any* XML (incl. MathXML) in PHP by using an XML parser like `DOMDocument` or `SimpleXML` which is available in PHP.

Comment: So you are asking how to parse XML in PHP? There is a plethora of resources available on that, e.g. when Googling `php parse xml`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/de/book.simplexml.php) to parse a XML file.

Edit:

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlstring);
var_dump($xml)
echo $xml->yournode;
?>
```

Comment: Guys  
Check this original XML  http://www.abcbets.com/dependencies/org_xml.xml   ... I need to take the particular tag value i.e mathDisplay . Unable to read DOMDocument or SimpleXML . Please help me

Comment: There is an error on your page. Is it correct? error on line 7 at column 23: Namespace prefix xlink for href on linkSource is not defined

Comment: well its a well formed XML. All tags are valid only. If you open in browser then it will show error. I just need to find the exact tag content

Comment: You got an error because you use xlink:href and this is not defined in your context. I think i dont understand your problem.